# could i initialize an object inside it's class?

Tags: java

I was trying to make a class "Date" in Java so I wrote this:

```
class Date
{
    private  int year, month, day;  

    Date(int year, int month, int day)   
    { this.year = year; this.month = month; this.day = day; }

    Date today = new Date(2016,3,14);         

    public int addDaysTo(Date someDate) { // <<------- this supposed to calculate number of days required to achieve passed date from today

        int def = convToDays(someDate) - convToDays(today);

        if (def < 0) return -1;

        return def;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error: stack overflow.  I think this was because of the line

```
 Date today = new Date(2016,3,14);
```

I understand initializing an object inside its own class would cause an infinite loop, but if I need to identify some Date constant to be used like in addDaysTo method, what should I do?!

I tried moving the problematic line to a new class and make it static like this:

```
class stupidSol
{
    static Date today = new Date(2016,3,14);     
}
```

This worked (after replacing today by stupidSol.today of course) but I think there might be an easier way.  Is there?

Comment: just make today static in Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this line leads to a stack overflow error.

```
Date today = new Date(2016,3,14);
```

You have found what causes it, and here is why.  When you create a `Date`, it has as an instance variable `today`, which creates another `Date`, which creates another `Date`, and so on, until your stack overflows.

Making it `static` solves the problem, because then `today` is initialized only once, and not as part of every instance that is created.

You made it as part of another class, which will work, but you can make it `static` within your own `Date` class, to make it cleaner, more understandable, and more readable.